# Diagnosing regular crashes with data loss?

Tags: linux, kernel, crash

I'm on Kubuntu 15.04 on a HP zBook 14. Every few days, my computer locks up completely - screen stays on, sound get stuck and plays the last few tenths of a second of what ever was playing over and over. The kernel doesn't respond to [magic keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) (`alt+ctrl + prtsrc, r,e,i,s,u,b` - this works at other times). The only way I can get out of it is to hard reset with the power button. If I do this, the sound stops after 1-2 seconds of holding down the button. If I let go, it starts again. If I hold it down for 5 seconds, the computer restarts.

The only real sign on rebooting, is that some files (open files, I guess?), have a new line at the end that consists of a bunch of non-printing characters that show up in vim like

```
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

The only reason I noticed this is that my `.zsh_history` usually gets corrupted, but I've seen this in other files too (e.g. a `.git/log/HEAD` file).

I've checked logs:

- `kernel.log` - I can't see anything relevant in the time before the crash, but at the time, there's a line similar to the `.zsh_history`
- `syslog` - also nothing, also with one of those lines
- `Xorg.*.log` - can't see anything here, but I'm not sure what how to decode the log index...
- `demsg` - ends with a lot of lines like `[17590.906375] retire_capture_urb: 11 callbacks suppressed` - no idea if that's relevant.
- `lastlog` - consists of one *very long* line (25k chars) with the same characters as the `.zsh_history` as mentioned above.
- `faillog` - as lastlog, but 35k characters.

I can't see any other relevant ones. If there's any more info I can provide, please let me know.

Has anyone ever seen a crash like this, and might be able to tell me where I could start looking for a fix?

Comment: 1. FYI, those `^@` are NUL bytes, `\000`.  2. do you have another machine on the local network that you can configure your syslogd to send kernel log entries to? that may help.

Comment: @cas This is a laptop, I'm often moving around, but I could see if I could find a computer to set something like that up on... Is there a good tutorial for how to do it anywhere?

Comment: here's how to do it if you're using `rsyslog`: http://www.rsyslog.com/sending-messages-to-a-remote-syslog-server/ - you probably want remote logging of `kern.*` rather than `*.*`.

Comment: Thanks @cas. I will see if I can get that set up somewhere.